# Problema com acentuação ao executar script python direto do C#

Tags: c#, python, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou usando isso pra rodar o código:

```
processo.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"\Python27\python.exe",
    Arguments = arquivoResposta,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true
};
```

Aqui um exemplo da saída correta:

```
Média mensal de atendimentos: 13.17
----
Mês 5: 17
Mês 7: 14
Mês 8: 14
Mês 11: 23
Mês 12: 30
```

O que está saindo:

```
MÃ©dia mensal de atendimentos: 13.17

----

MÃªs 5: 17

MÃªs 7: 14

MÃªs 8: 14

MÃªs 11: 23

MÃªs 12: 30
```

Alguém tem uma solução? Tentei usar também o output.normalize(), mas ainda nada.

Comment: Edite o script em python (arquivoResposta) colocando logo na primeira linha `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` e veja se alterou o resultado. E o que acontece se você executar o mesmo código diretamente pelo cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que quando você executa um script Python direto pelo command, ele pode detectar a codificação do terminal (que é "cp-852") e codificar a saída de acordo.

Quando você roda a partir de outro processo, o Python não tem como adivinhar a codificação do terminal, e usa utf-8 por padrão. Isso se for Python3, ou se você usou strings Unicode de forma correta, ou próximo do correto em Python2 - senão pode ser o caso de você estar usando utf-8 hardcoded mesmo.

Quando você tenta exibir texto acentuado, codificado em utf-8 numa saída latin-1, a acentuação é exibida errada da forma que você postou (cada caractére acentuado se desdobra em dois, sendo que o primeiro é um "Ã" )

Primeiro você tem que entender o que está acotnecendo quando trata de codificação de acentos. Não adianda pergunta,r copiar e colar respostas, ou tentar ficar alterando parametros para  "encode" e "decode" ao acaso.
[Esse artigo tem uma boa introdução](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)).

Se o seu programa em Python2 está usando byte-strings, então ele está hard-coded para utf-8 mesmo  -  e se você executa-lo direto do command vai ver a acentuação errada, mas de outro jeito.

ENtão, segunda coisa - tente usar Python 3.6.0 ou 3.5 em vez de Python 2.7-  não há sentido usar uma versão tao antiga do Python em um projeto novo, e a maior mudança do Python2 para Python3 é justamente o tratamento automático da codificação de acentos em alguns dos casos.

Se o problema persistir, é por que, como eu disse no primeiro parágrafo, não tem como realmente o Python adivinhar a codificação da sua saída a partir dos dados que o C# envia para ele no redirecionamento. Nesse caso, você deverá forçar a codificação para latin-1. É bem pouco provável que esse seja o caso, por que é bem difícil forçar o "print" do Python a usar outra codificação para o stdout que não seja a que está lá. O que eu acredito que seja o seu caso, como em Python2, é você ter usado byte-strings (isso é, sem o prefixo `u"..."` em Python2) e etar com seu arquivo código fonte hardcoded em utf-8. Ao passar a usar Python3, a coisa se resolve.

Senão, outra forma de resolver é salvar seu arquivo.py com a codificação "latin1" diretamente. Nesse caso,a sa alteraçẽos devm ser feitas apenas no seu editor de textos de programação, e a primeira ou segunda linha que indica a codificação do arquivo deve ser mudade de "# coding:utf-8" para  "# coding: latin1" . Seu programa funcionará sem alterações, mas você vai perder muitas das ferramentas para processamento de texto de forma correta - por isso a dica para mudar para Python 3.